# Can I use {{page.date}} with a Collection has format YYYY-MM-DD-filename.md in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

From the document I read on Jekyll and around the Internet, posts in `_posts` directory is in `YYYY-MM-DD-filename.md` format and their date can be retrieved by using `{{page.date}}` Liquid variable without the need of specify a YAML front matter "date".

However, I created a Collection at the same level of `_posts`, called `_collections`. My question is: can I setup to retrieved the date of my markdown files in my collection without Front matter, like it is used in `_posts`?

Additionally, I want to know how can markdown files in `_posts` can have this property? And if there's a solution, can I use it with Github Pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have a collection page with this url `/folder/2015-11-29-some-words-here.html`, you can mimic posts date with :

```
{% assign fileName = page.url | split: "/" | last %}

{% assign elements = fileName | split: "-" %}

{% capture dateString %}{{elements[0]}}-{{elements[1]}}-{{elements[2]}}{% endcapture %}

{{ dateString | date: "%a, %b %d, %y" }}
```

[For more information on Liquid date formating](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/additional-filters#date)

Comment: How about having a few pages in the collection, not only one?

Comment: Sorry I've edited my code. It's now ok to use on every collection page. You can put it in an include.